# Replacement for autocomplete_light.modelform_factory()

Tags: django, django-autocomplete-light

I'm trying to update from 2.2.10 to the current version, but my projects uses `autocomplete_light.modelform_factory()` several times to generate forms for creating new models on the admin side.

Like this in admin.py:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = autocomplete_light.modelform_factory(MyModel, fields='__all__')
    list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name')
```

What's the new way to generate model forms in `django-autocomplete-light==3.1.6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to talk to the maintainer of autocomplete-light on IRC (#your-labs). He said there is no replacement yet (as of version 3.1.6)

So for now, I'm holding off on upgrading. I'll update this answer if something new comes out.